# Find a basis for the subspace $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $2$. Let $U$ be the subspace of $V$ defined by $U=\{p \in V : p'(1)=0 \}$. I wish to find a basis of $U$.

Let $p=ax^2+bx+c.$ So in order for $p$ to be an element of $U$ it must satisfy $2a+b=0.$ Or equivalently, $p$ must be of the form $ax^2-2ax+c=ax(x-2)+c$.

I'm still not sure how this enables me to find a basis for $U$ though.

Comment: Just fix some values for $a$ and $c$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. So $\{x(x-2),1\}$ would be a basis?

Comment: Yes, for example.